# Summarizing rows based on column values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to summarize rows together based on aggregate column values.

[image]

Is there a way to use grouping and aggregate statements to do this, or do I need to give up and use a cursor?  If so, what would that cursor look like?

Comment: Is there a field that determines order in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Route
    ,MIN(From_Milepost) From_MilePost
    ,MAX(To_Milepost) To_MilePost
    ,Pavement_Condition
FROM [yourTable]

GROUP BY PavementCondition
          ,Route
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Always glad to help!

Comment: @E.Monk FYI, think you're missing a `Route` in your group by